# Consider $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ and solve $f(z)=0$

Tags: polynomials

$f(z)=z^3+9z+26$ and $g(z)=z^2+26z-27$ are two equations that are related in a way where $f(z-\frac{3}{z})=\frac{g(z^3)}{z^3}$

I've already proven the relationship above, as they both equate to $z^3+26-\frac {27}{z^3}$, but what am I supposed to do with that knowledge to solve $f(z)=0$?

Comment: Please clarify, what have you been given as question? Is the relation of $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ given in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise makes it easier for you since you've proven that :

$$f(z-\frac{3}{z})=\frac{g(z^3)}{z^3}$$

which you can substitute with :

$$z := w-\frac3w$$

and plug in $f$, thus solving essentialy for $w$ and then for $z$.

But I guess, solving $f(z) = 0$ is more straightforward and elementary by factorization :

$$f(z) = 0 \Leftrightarrow z^3+9z+26 = 0 \Leftrightarrow (z+2)(z^2 -2z +13) = 0$$

which tells us that the roots are :

$$z= -2, z = 1 - 2i\sqrt3, z=1+ 2i\sqrt3$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f(z)=0$. can you wind $w$ with $z==w-\frac3w$? What can you say about $g(w^3)$? Hence what are the possible values of $w$ and ultimately of $z$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $g(1) = 0$. Thus from $f(z-\frac{3}{z})=\frac{g(z^3)}{z^3}$, you have  $f(-2) = 0$. Other two roots of $f(z) = 0$ can be found using quadratic formula.

Alternatively you can also find one more root of $f(z) = 0$ using the other root of $g(z) = 0$ which is $-27$.